# Are Ubuntu OEm kernel features ever integrated to mainline?

Tags: kernel, oem

The Ubuntu OEM kernel delivers better support for my device.

Are the features of the OEM kernel ever integrated to the mainline kernel or will the device always depend on the OEM kernel?

Comment: What are you calling "mainline"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many cases, yes, the OEM features will eventually appear in the mainline version of the kernel.

I think that the OEM has two concepts: (1) it includes drivers that are for hardware not found in common computers (2) it is a test bed for new hardware.

For (1), I don't think you're likely to see those drivers appear in the mainline version.

For (2), it is a transitory release for people who are on the edge allowing development and testing as early as possible. Once it is considered (very) stable, then the driver makes it to mainline *in the next version*. That is, you will probably never see support for your device in 20.04. You probably will have to wait for 20.10 or 21.04. It may also never make it there if somehow the sales of that hardware do not match the development costs...

More info: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel